# LogCat Exception: ApacheHttpTransport not working even though added in android

Tags: java, android, google-api, google-places-api

I am trying to design an app which uses HttpTransport in my Android project but, on calling the import, it throws the below Logcat errors.

```
E/dalvikvm(481): Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport', referenced from method com.test.main.MyActivity.<clinit>
W/dalvikvm(413): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 75 (Lcom/google/api/client/http/javanet/NetHttpTransport;) in Lcom/test/main/MyActivity
W/dalvikvm(481): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport;)
I/dalvikvm(481): Failed resolving Lcom/test/main/MyActivity$2; interface 71 'Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestInitializer;'
D/dalvikvm(481): VFY: dead code 0x0002-0009 in Lcom/test/main/MyActivity;.createRequestFactory (Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport;)Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpRequestFactory;
E/dalvikvm(481): Could not find class 'com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl', referenced from method
```

I've tried searching in the site for solutions but they look hazy or not worth the need. Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong here?

I've imported all the dependencies JARs in my project but still, it doesn't work.

I use Google API Version 1.8.3.
Main source: google-api-java-client-1.8.3-beta.jar

All dependencies are included for the above JAR in the .zip file inclusive of external JARs that have been recommended by Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Happens like the import wasn't proper.

Plus it is that, I had to link it properly in Eclipse under Libraries.

I used com.google.api.client.http.ApacheHttpTransport than the standard library suggesteed by Eclipse.

And now it works.
Cheers!